# Regex: find capitalized words

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I find and extract capitalized words of a string with regex?

I would like to:

1. extract the capitalized words of a string, as an array
2. extract the last capitalized word of a string, as a substring:

Both with one regex

If I have this:

```
var str="This is a STRING of WORDS to search";
```

I would like to get this 1:

```
allCapWords // = ["STRING", "WORDS"]
```

and 2:

```
lastCapWord // = "WORDS"
```

Comment: There are two sections with "I would like to". I think you wanted to replace the last one with the section "I tried this.... But got this... ".

Comment: I ask for two variations of a solution: 1. for all words and 2. for just the last one.

Have edited question. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598315/regex-to-match-only-uppercase-words-with-some-exceptions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To extract the words into an array:

```
var allCapWords = str.match(/\b[A-Z]+\b/g);
-> ["STRING", "WORDS"]
```

([Here's a Regex101 test](https://regex101.com/r/iN5zS2/1) with your string.)

To pull the last word:

```
var lastCapWord = allCapWords[allCapWords.length - 1];
-> "WORDS"
```

Comment: The first is a good answer.
Could you make a match for the last one? for instance with look ahead? (?=)

Answer (score 2):

```
 var str="This is a STRING of WORDS to search";
 var regObj =  /\b([A-Z]+)\b/g;  
 allCapWords = str.match(regObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regexpr `/\b[A-Z]+\b/g`or `\b[A-Z0-9]+\b/g` if you are interested in catch numbers inside the string