# Special Regex/ Extraction of All Capitalized words which also has special characters like "-" , "/", "\" etc

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regex I want to capture multiple capital words.
Sometime capital words can have special characters between them.

**example 1:**

```
string = string = 'MY MANAGEMENT PRIOR ASSESSMENT / NEW PLANNING SUPRESS RATE  - TEAM : 14
```

I want the regex to capture all capital words and the special characters that seperate them

```
"MY MANAGEMENT PRIOR ASSESSMENT / NEW PLANNING SUPRESS RATE  - TEAM"
```

**example 2:**

```
string2 = 'SPORT/TRACK INFO  ¶·»Sport Coverage(s): All Sport  primary ¶·»WWE Hi-Low:  ¶·»BBC Hi-Low: ¶·»Sports Issues: can run forever ¶·»BBC Sports: kjkj '
```

I want the regex to capture `"SPORT/TRACK INFO", "WWE", "BBC"`

Comment: This post should probably help for what you are looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598315/regex-to-match-only-uppercase-words-with-some-exceptions.

Comment: about the second example. solution is `[A-Z]+\b` or `(?! )\b[A-Z\/ ]+\b(?!\w)`

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: This returns:  ['SPORT', 'TRACK', 'INFO', 'S', 'C', 'A', 'S', 'WWE', 'H', 'L', 'BBC', 'H', 'L', 'S', 'I', 'BBC', 'S']

Comment: @ryanb my solution for second regex

Comment: I tried re.findall('[A-Z]+', string2)

Comment: @ryanb https://regex101.com/r/T0xEBi/1

Comment: Not a duplicate of a **_Reference_** !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the capital words need to be separate from lower case letters
and can have space, -, /, \ between the words, would be this  :

`[A-Z](?<![a-zA-Z][A-Z])(?:[A-Z]|[-\s/\\])*(?<=[A-Z])(?![a-zA-Z])`

https://regex101.com/r/28FR7s/1

---

Python ***`findall()`*** example code

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> string1 = 'MY MANAGEMENT PRIOR ASSESSMENT / NEW PLANNING SUPRESS RATE - TEAM : 14'
>>> string2 = 'SPORT/TRACK INFO ¶·»Sport Coverage(s): All Sport primary ¶·»WWE Hi-Low: ¶·»BBC Hi-Low: ¶·»Sports Issues: can run forever ¶·»BBC Sports: kjkj '
>>>
>>> Rx = r"[A-Z](?<![a-zA-Z][A-Z])(?:[A-Z]|[-\s/\\])*(?<=[A-Z])(?![a-zA-Z])"
>>>
>>> re.findall( Rx, string1 )
['MY MANAGEMENT PRIOR ASSESSMENT / NEW PLANNING SUPRESS RATE - TEAM']
>>> re.findall( Rx, string2 )
['SPORT/TRACK INFO', 'WWE', 'BBC', 'BBC']
```

Comment: I've deleted mine and voted for yours.

Comment: Thank you this works. Do you have a solution in find All in Python.

Comment: @ryanb - Added a Python sample solution.