# Regex to match on capital words, with some exceptions in javascript

Tags: javascript

Consider the following strings which would match:

- HELLO WORLD HOW ARE YOU?
- HELLO world HOW are YOU?
- I am a SERIES OF WORDS that are capital
- I am INVALID.

While these would not match:

- Hello TV // (tv is not a word)
- Come to my BBQ at my 1200 SQ.FT House.

The rule is very simple: No all capital words. (abbreviations are fine, words are not)

Currently I have:

```
^(?!.*\b[A-Z]{2,}\b).*$
```

[this is the closest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598315/regex-to-match-only-uppercase-words-with-some-exceptions) but it is almost opposite of what I am trying to do.

I am not good with regex at all, I have tried various online tools and this is as close as I got. I believe the issue lies with the fact it should be something like \w or \W as I want words, not individual characters and not abbreviations like TV, BBQ, SQ.FT and so on, they have to be full on words as indicated above.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to this with just regex. You are going to need a list of valid words to compare your strings to. `\w` and `\W` match word characters (or the inverse), but do not differentiate between actual words and not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular Expressions on their own cannot do this. You would need a separate dictionary with a list of all words that you do not want to be matched, then rule them out afterwards.

Comment: Yup, you could also store the words that need to be matched (easier to achieve, though the list would still be enormous)